# How to make Android Studio bottom tool window size to full wide

Tags: android-studio

My other machine have bottom tool window full width, so I believe this can be achieved, unfortunately I don't remember how I do that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Intellij support discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206721315/comments/360000800199)

> It's Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Widescreen tool window layout!